# Why does (.) map have this type?

Tags: haskell, types

I tried to find the type of the function `(.) map` but somehow find that it is `((a -> d) -> (a -> e)) -> ([d] -> [e])` which according to GHCI is not correct because it should be `(.) map :: (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> [a2] -> [b]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Deriving the type...

We have as ingredients:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
map :: (d -> e) -> [d] -> [e]
```

(here I used different type identifiers for the two functions to avoid any confusion). A more verbose form (where we make it more explicit that every function takes exactly *one* parameter) is:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
map :: (d -> e) -> ([d] -> [e])
```

Since `map` is the first parameter of `(.)` that means that its type `(d -> e) -> ([d] -> [e])` should match the input type of the `(.)` function (so `b -> c`). This thus means:

```
  b        -> c
~ (d -> e) -> ([d] -> [e])
------------------------------
b ~ (d -> e), c ~ ([d] -> [e])
```

So that means that the result type of `(.) map` is:

```
(a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(a -> (d -> e)) -> (a -> ([d] -> [e]))
```

or less verbose:

```
(.) map :: (a -> d -> e) -> a -> [d] -> [e]
```

## ... and its implementation

The `(.)` function can be seen as `(.) f g == \x -> f (g x)`. So that means that our function

```
h = (.) map
```

is equivalent to:

```
h f x = map (f x)
```

It thus takes as input a function `f` and an object `x`, and than performs a `map` with `f x` as function.

Semancially you could say that we make a "*map where one has to inject a 'contect'-objecct*" of type `a`. This context is then taken into account by the processor. This could be useful if we want to apply multiple `map`s, each with a small change, and thus first pass a "context-object". This is of course *an* interpretation of humans. For a compiler, the `x` can have any use, interpretation, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You have probably tried to match the functions by looking at the definition

```
Types of the two functions
(.) :: ((b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c)
map :: (d -> e) -> [d] -> [e]
```

and then trying to match `d` to `b` and `e` to `c`. Which gives you `((a -> d) -> (a -> e)) -> ([d] -> [e])`, now you could match `[d]` to `a` and `[e]` to `d`. This is however not correct because according to the type definition of `map`, `e` and `d` could be of different type, i.e. `d` could be of type `[e]` but it doesn't have to.

The correct way to find the type of this function is to look at the definition of the types

```
Types of the two functions
(.) :: ((b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c)
map :: (d -> e) -> [d] -> [e]
```

and then to match `(d -> e)` to `b` and `[d] -> [e]` to `c` which gives you `(a -> (d -> e)) -> a -> ([d] -> [e])`, by removing the superfluous brackets and renaming the type variables you get `(a -> b -> c) -> a -> [b] -> [c]`. This is the same result GHCI gives you.

Answer (score 3):

When I don't understand the type of a function, I write types using different letters:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
map :: (x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]
```

now we are providing `map` as the first argument of `(.)` so we can deduce:

```
b -> c == (x -> y) -> [x] -> [y] -- by matching first arguments we get...
b == x -> y                      
c == [x] -> [y]
```

since we have already provided the first argument of `(.)`, the whole `b -> c` part disappears.

```
(.) map :: (a -> b) -> a -> c                -- Using the above equations for b and c
(.) map :: (a -> x -> y) -> a -> [x] -> [y]  -- changing variables names
(.) map :: (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> [a2] -> [b]
```

as `GHCi` plots

Comment: Usually the tilde (`~`) is used to denote that two types are the same. Nevertheless +1 :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem didn't know it. Thanks for sharing :)